# Having trouble uploading files from Javascript and receiving it through Go

Tags: javascript, go, mux

I set up a simple frontend service in JavaScript using Axios. This service takes a list of files and sends to my server code using a post request. My JavaScript looks like this

```
const testPost = async (files) => {
  let formData = new FormData();

  files.forEach((file) => {
    formData.append("file", file);
  });

  const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: baseUrl,
    data: formData,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  });

  return res;
};
```

And my Go code looks like this:

```
func (h *SendHandler) TestPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Allow CORS here By * or specific origin
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

    formdata := r.MultipartForm
    fmt.Println(formdata)
}
```

I think my problem lies in the body of my TestPost function in Go because I click send in my frontend code, I receive a response. In my Go function, when I print my formdata, it outputs `<nil>`. I want to be able to access each file in the list but I can't even access the formdata. I'm still new to both web dev and Go so there is definitely something I am misunderstanding here. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for MultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.MultipartForm) says:

> MultipartForm is the parsed multipart form, including file uploads. This field is only available after ParseMultipartForm is called.

Fix by calling [ParseMultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm) before using `r.MultipartForm`.

```
err := r.ParseMultipartForm(maxMemory)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Bad Request", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
// r.MultipartForm is now set.
fmt.Println(r.MultipartForm)  // does not print nil
```